Intersection between causal future and causal past
I am trying to show that for a closed, achronal surface $S$ the intersection of its causal past $J^-(S)$ and causal future $J^+(S)$ is the surface itself, i.e.
$$S = J^+(S) \cap J^-(S)$$
Note that I do not know for certain this is true, but I have the feeling that it might.

By definition of causal past and causal future we can easily show that
$$S \subseteq J^+(S) \quad  \text{and} \quad S \subseteq J^-(S) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad S \subseteq J^+(S) \cap J^-(S)$$
However, I have problems showing that $J^+(S) \cap J^-(S) \subseteq S$.
Clearly if $p \in J^+(S) \cap J^-(S)$ then there must exist $p_{+} \in S$ and $p_{-} \in S$ such that $p \in J^+(p_+)$ and $p \in J^-(p_-)$. But since $S$ is achronal, it must also hold that either $p \notin I^+(p_+)$ or $p \notin I^-(p_-)$, otherwise $p_+$ and $p_-$ could be connected by a timelike curve through $p$. So it remains to either show that $p \in S$. Unfortunately, I do not know how. I would be glad if anyone had hints, tips or suggestions.

Does your argument work when you specialize it to Godel's spacetime?

Is this related to the coordinate origin of Kruskal Szekeres chart where we a single point that is both $t = +\infty$ at the event horizon of the black hole and $t = -\infty$ at the white hole horizon.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates

Well, you have problems to prove that $J^+(S) \cap J^-(S)\subset S$ because it may be false.
For that reason the claim is generally false. Consider $S_0$ defined as the closed future lightcone surface $t=|\vec{x}|$ in $\mathbb{R}^{1,n-1}$. Define $$S:= S_0 \setminus B_r(p)$$
where $p \in S_0$ and $B_r(p)$ is a $\mathbb{R}^n$ open ball of sufficiently small radius $r>0$ such that $\partial B_r(p)$ does not touch the tip of the cone.
$S_0$ is closed, acronal, but $J^+(S) \cap J^-(S) \ni p$ which does not belong to $S$.
